# can a program set up temporary server space on google compute engine? (or any cloud service)

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to develop a program to make use of google compute engine for rendering images using pov ray. the program needs to be used in commercial software and it would be ideal if the user payed for the server space/ computing power needed for their rendering DIRECTLY rather than rendering on a server we own and then them pay us. is this possible? If not on google, does anyone know a cloud service that CAN do this?
Any help would greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this with Google Compute Engine.  The user would need to follow the [seven getting started steps](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/signup) so that they have a valid GCE account. You're application can then use [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) to make requests to GCE on behalf of the user. You would need to use [installed app flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp).